# php code to get count from multiselect listbox and store in database

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

Below is my textbox  values....i am unable to put my screen shots here..

i used multiple input tag jquery from this site..

http://loopj.com/jquery-tokeninput/demo.html

**and second option of this demo.** plz visit demo link ...

but i used multiple input textbox..in which we select multiple tags in one textbox okay.

like 700X 701X   702X

I need to get this textbox value and store in 3 rows..

FOR EX - in above screenshot there are 3 values 700,701,702 ok...now i need to ask you...when i click save i need to store this values in 3 different rows...

```
Rows No   -   used_receipt
 1                 700
 2                 701
 3                 702
```

i try like below but wont work...

**textbox code**

```
<input  id="demo-input-local" type="text"  value="<?php echo $data['used_receipt'];?>" name="used_receipt" />
```

**javascript**

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#demo-input-local").tokenInput([
<?php 
$receipt = $database->getRows("SELECT DISTINCT SM.receipt_no FROM scheme_master SM Inner join book_issue BI ON BI.book_no = SM.Book_no2  where SM.receipt_no not in (select used_receipt from book_return)");       
 foreach($receipt as $row){ ?>

                {name: "<?php echo $row['receipt_no']; ?>"},
               <?php } ?>


            ]);
        });
        </script>
```

**php code to insert multiple values in database**

```
$used_receipt = $_POST['used_receipt']; 
$arr = explode(",", $used_receipt);
$max = count($arr);

for ($i = 0; $i < $max; $i++)
{
$insertrow = $database->insertRow("INSERT INTO book_return (book,surveyor,used_receipt,city,return_date,created)    
                         VALUES  (:book,:surveyor,:used_receipt,:city,:return_date,:created)",  
                         array(':used_receipt'=>$arr[$i]);              
}
```

Comment: And.. What error are you getting ?

Comment: i am not getting any error but my values are not inserting in database....i need to insert two row if select tag has two value like wise....plz help....

Comment: i update my full code...plz

Comment: Try a `var_dump($arr)` before loop and as i have not used queries with : so are you sure ur query is correct ?

Comment: yes my query is working fine and getting all data in autocomplete listbox....prob. is to insert this in databse..

Comment: There would be an error in json as well . There is comma that might be creating probs

Comment: What is `var_dump` giving u ?

Comment: all column are inserting values in database....except used_receipt is not inserting any values in database...var_dump shows like array
  0 => string '' (length=0)

Comment: Error is in js then. I wonder there might be a need of id as well.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
foreach($receipt as $row){ ?>

            {name: "<?php echo $row['receipt_no']; ?>"},
           <?php } ?>
```

Try this

```
$r = array();$i=1;
foreach($receipt as $row){ 
$r[]['name'] = $row['receipt_no'];$r[]['id'] = $i++;
}
echo "JSON.parse(\"".json_encode($t)."\")";
```

Comment: And may be remove those square brackets before and after also (`[]`)

Comment: thanks darshan ...i done this...and also done insert code...but thanks for reply...

Answer (score 0):

below is script which i used

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#demo-input-local").tokenInput([<?php 
$receipt = $database->getRows("SELECT DISTINCT SM.receipt_no FROM scheme_master SM Inner join book_issue BI ON BI.book_no = SM.Book_no2");      
 foreach($receipt as $row){ ?>          
               {id:<?php echo $row['receipt_no']; ?>,name: "<?php echo $row['receipt_no']; ?>"},
               <?php } ?>
            ]);
        });
        </script>
```

and get this input in like

```
$used_receipt = $_POST['used_receipt']; 
            $arr = explode(",", rtrim($used_receipt));
```